# Pullback of tangent sheaves for two finite covers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm new on the forum.

I've a strange question but it's puzzling me. Consider a compact projective Calabi-Yau $M$ of complex dimension $n$, and two finite ramified covers : $$\gamma : M \longrightarrow X \,\, and \,\, f: M \longrightarrow  Y$$ respectively ramified over $\Delta$ and $D$. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have ample tangent bundles. Can we deduce relations between the Chern classes of $\gamma^* TX$ and $f^* TY$ ?

In the particular case where $X = \mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y$ is a flag manifold, can $\gamma^* T\mathbb{P}^n$ and $f^* TY$ have no relation ?

Can express the Chern classes from those of $TM$ and $\gamma^* \mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ (resp. $f^* \mathcal{K}_Y$)?

Thanks for reading,

Comment: I don't know why, but i initially wrote "Hello everybody". It disappeared. Sorry.

Comment: Why would you expect any relation? $M$ could be $M_1\times M_2$ and $X=X_1\times M_2$, $Y=M_1\times Y_1$ and then I do not see any possible relations.

Comment: You're right : i tried to make the question much general. But in the particular setting : $X = \mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y$ is a flag manifold , i had the feeling that the pullbacks have to be isomorphic. If we pullback a vector field on$\mathbb{P}^n$ as a meromorphic one on $M$, and if the pole is not on the ramification locus of $f$ then we can pushforward locally as a local meromorphic vector field with pole on $Y$, not supported on its canonical sheaf. Am i wrong?